# Access scss variable from <template> of VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, sass

In my VueJS project, I have a `variables.scss` file which contains a few variables that I usually `@import`in the `<style/>` section of my components when I need them locally. This works fine, but how can I use one of those variables when I need them as attributes to an element of my template? In my case, I am trying to use my primary color as the `bar-color` attribute of a `progress-bar` ([See here for this component's doc](https://github.com/dzwillia/vue-simple-progress)).

Here is what I have tried without success, even after importing the variable file in my style section :

```
<template>
...
<progress-bar :val="value" size="large" bar-color="$primary"></progress-bar>
...
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../assets/styles/variables.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: I think you can't as scss variables are resolved at compile time rather than run time. You can use a class which is using that variable.

Comment: the only thing with this approach is that I should dive into the progress-bar code in order to know which css selector I should target but this sounds manageable, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your variables in a javascript file, import the file into your component and then access them from that instead?

Comment: why would you write an extra js file to contain the same variables that your s[a|c]ss file already has? sounds like a hack and not the solution

Answer (score 6):

Try this [out](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript), Declare your variables in scss file and export it.

like this 
**In scss**

```
$white-color: #fff;

:export {
  whitecolor: $white-color;
}
```

**In ts**

```
import variables from 'variables.scss';

primary = variables.whitecolor;
```

**In HTML**

```
<progress-bar :val="value" size="large" :bar-color="primary"></progress-bar>
```

Comment: you need to declare scss in global.d.ts first and then you also need to rename the scss file as *.module.scss. Please do not just copy the solution from a random website and actually test it out yourself first.